# Can I use method pointers in c++ alike delegates in c#?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods

I would like to make a class' (let's call it X for convenience) method be able to use a pointer to its own methods in cases where I would be able to extract code that differs only by the method called.

for example, having a few blocks like:

```
a();
b();
c();
MehtodCall(someResultOfabc);
d();
e();
```

I would like to extract a method that would just use different methods passed as a pointer:

so I would like something alike:

```
void X::ExtractedMethod( void(X::*MethodCallPointer)(TypeOfABCResult) ){
    a();
    b();
    c();
    this->*MethodCallPointer(someResultOfabc);
    d();
    e();
}
```

and use this very function in such manner:

```
void X::DoSomethingA(){
    ExtractedMethod(&X::ADoer);
}
void X::DoSomethingB(){
    ExtractedMethod(&X::BDoer);
}
```

and os on...

Unfortunately I am stuck here, because I get a compile error, that the method pointer doesn't evaluate to a method call which takes one argument.

I start to wander if the reason would be that X is yet an incomplete type in this declaration ?

I would be happy if someone would help me by telling how to do this, or why isn't that possible.

What I really, really DON'T want is to get some workarounds, like using std::function in the signature and a lambda, or using a pointer to a static methods that takes X* and invoke specific methods that I need, nor making switch statements and a flag, nor instead of that switch statement use an interface, implement the strategy patern and use static instances of strategies as a parameter ;) those aren't all workaround for this case, but I stil don't want to read about other workarounds. The sole thing that interests me is "is that possible, and how to do it" in this very way.

Comment: What are the signatures of `X::ADoer` and `X::BDoer`?

Comment: It's not called "method", it's called "member function" in C++.

Comment: @Griwes *method* is a generic, language-agnostic OOP concept. That concept maps without ambiguity to C++'s member functions so the term can perfectly be used even in C++. ;)

Comment: @syam, it's not a correct C++ term and the discussion is about C++. C++ is standardised, and a standard term is member function, so use it. Generic terms might be used, when the discussion is generic, but when it's specific, you should always use specific terms. And, since it's not well defined in context of C++, it becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @Griwes: please keep your off-topic to yourself next time. I have used a generic word so there were no doubts on what I mean. Arguing about naming them "methods" or "member functions" is without any meaning in this topic. If you wish to argue on that topic then please create your own "question" so that you can argue on nonexistant problems there, instead of spamming here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user2511124, let me repeat once again: you asked a question about an ISO standardized language, defined in ISO 14882. If you decided to do so, you should use *standard* terms, not some generic ones pulled from outside the scope of the language. If you cannot understand such simple fact, I feel pity for your lack of understanding of English language and/or lack of ability to comprehend written text. And keeping language purity is hardly ever offtopic; it's like correcting grammar or spelling mistakes someone does, which is likely never offtopic.

Comment: @syam: Actually, C++ member functions (*especially non-`virtual` member functions*) do not have all the characteristics of methods.  Using the term in C++ is not correct, even though people know what was actually meant (because as you said, it's unambiguously the closest feature).

Answer (score 3):

@Robert is right, the idiomatic way to use delegates in C++ is to use `std::function` along with `std::bind`.

However, if you insist on using pointers-to-methods as a workaround to proper delegates, the right syntax is:

```
void X::ExtractedMethod( void(X::*MethodCallPointer)(TypeOfABCResult) ){
    (this->*MethodCallPointer)(someResultOfabc);
//  ^                        ^
//  note the parentheses, they are required
```

Comment: @syam: aw, I've missed those parentheses.. now I understand why didn't it compile. This is just what I was asking for :) I did use an std::function and a lambda after I have failed with this approach. I've let myself do it this way, because the "do all the things" method is private. But I must say, that I like this solution with boost::bind too, because it seems more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use boost bind to bind the function call:

```
void X::DoSomethingA(){
    ExtractedMethod( boost::bind(&X::ADoer, pInstance) );
}
```

The pInstance is needed if X::ADoer isn't a static member of class X.

For the function type you'd use either std::function (latest C++) or boost::function.

```
typedef std::function< void(TypeOfABCResult) > MyDelegateType;

void X::ExtractedMethod( MyDelegateType delegate ) { ... }
```

And this isn't a workaround. It IS how you do it in C++, and it works every bit similar to how it works in C# with delegates.

Comment: From the question, it appears that he doesn't *want* to bind the instance.

Comment: In that case he probably doesn't know exactly what he is asking for, or maybe his solution architecture is incorrect and he's asking the wrong question ;)